# standalone exe in Qt

Tags: qt, exe

I want to make a standalone .exe file in Qt msvc 2010 5. I change the mode to "release" and build my project and I copy the .exe file in release/debug folder to bin directory in Qt directory and then I copy all the bin folder. it works properly in my computer, but when I move the bin folder to other computers the .exe file doesn't work. I installed visual c++ 2010 redistributable package in the other computer but still it doesn't work. what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is most likely that the other machine doesn't have Qt installed. If you want a wholly standalone Qt app on Windows (statically linked), check this out: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows

Some quick build instructions -

1. Make sure you have python installed and in your path Get the Qt
   source code
   (http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1.zip)
2. unzip the zip file and open a Visual Studio command prompt in that
   directory
3. execute `configure -static -release -no-audio-backend
   -opengl desktop -opensource -confirm-license`
4. execute `nmake` (this will compile all of Qt and will take a while depending on your processing power)
5. add CONFIG+=static to your .pro file call `qmake` from the build of qt you
   just made and then run `nmake` on your project. You'll then get a
   statically linked binary. You'll know because even a very small
   program will be > 5MB in size.

Comment: for microsft msvc I have to use "configure" command, it's not a recognized command in visual studio command prompt. what is the problem?

Comment: The configure command is in the root of the Qt source tree. As the article explains "The first step is to build a static version of Qt". Qt itself is not normally built for static linking, so to achieve what you're attempting, you'll need to build Qt yourself first.

Comment: The other option is of course to distribute all of Qt along with your application.

Comment: I didn't get it. how can I build Qt myself?

Comment: The source code is available through git or as a download here: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Comment: my other question is how can I build it?(sorry i'm a noob)

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using currently?

Comment: I just executed configure. but nmake results NMAKE : fatal error 1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop.

Comment: the last problem solved. please answer this question:
[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149349/using-nmake-to-build-a-static-version-qt)

Comment: I built Qt, but there is no qmake in the directory. what is the problem?

Comment: It's in the qtbase\bin directory